# Using jQuery to remove a second form element without losing the child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some AJAX work that brings across an additional form element that I don't need in the DOM.  I don't have the ability to remove it server side, so I'm looking for some jQuery or classic JavaScript that will allow me to capture all the child elements of the form, remove the form I don't need and finally re-append the child elements back to the DOM.

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: Thanks for the quick answers, the below is what I actually used and it works perfect

```
            // Captures the children
            var children = $("form:eq(1)").children();
            // Removes the form
            $("form:eq(1)").remove();
            // append the child elements back into the DOM 
            $("#fillDiv").append(children);
```

Comment: @Toran: My solution would do what you asked, but you should probably be using something like @Staicu's solution rather than adding the form to the dom then trying to remove and and leave its children...

Comment: I just needed to easily be able to clear out a div whose child elements ids were unpredictably created.  I just used a slight variation on your solution:
$("#containerDiv").children().remove();

And I was so money and I didn't even know it.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using the `.html()` method (which will cause you to lose any events associated with form elements) you should move the child nodes:

```
// grab the child nodes
var children = $('#badForm').children();
// or var children = $('#badForm > *');

// move them to the body
$(body).append(children);

// remove the form
$('#badForm').remove();
```

Comment: @Toran: This will do what you asked, but you should probably be using something like @Staicu's solution rather than adding the form to the dom then trying to remove and and leave its children...

Answer (score 2):

If you have ajax code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "url",
    data: ,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

You can add on `success` function this:

```
$(data).find('#whatYouNeed').appendTo('#whereYouNeed')
```

In this way you can extract anything you want from that page :)

Comment: This is definitely a better option than adding the form to the dom then trying to extract it's children and removing it. @Toran, if you have an ajax call returning html then you should use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still actual, however there are better answers these days.

1. `unwrap` method: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/
2. `$element.replaceWith($element.contents());`